# Server Backup Options

Tags: linux, ssh, cron, backup, rsync

The hosting company (Newtek) which we are paying to host our websites does not tolerate SSH shell in shared Linux hosting plans. Initially I had in mind automating all the backup process (script for generating backups + cron job to automate the backup generating process on server side, while using a script with rsync + cron job on the receiving side to automate the rsync process) but since we can't SSH onto the server I can't figure out what would be the best way (excluding FTP) to automate the backup process without human intervention and in a secure manner. What are my options, in any?

Comment: See if they have a free backup service.  Many hosting companies that restrict SSH provide backup service.  Other than that, you could use PHP to execute shell commands and have another computer executed it with a cron job that uses wget to run the PHP.  Instead of rsync, you can use tar (assuming you don't have too much data).

Comment: There is a backup manager in cPanel which lets the user backup its data but that is not the problem. The problem resides in transferring those backups automatically out of the server. The hosting company also have included nightly backups up to 14 days but they required a 25USD payment for the user to have access to them! Regarding the PHP solution would you mind pointing me to a base code that I could adapt? I am not a php expert.